# Where do I put my object when using asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm relatively new to C# and VS, and currently having a play with ASP.NET, but I seem to be getting very muddled on where I should place my objects that I need to use within my webforms.  As a very basic example, how could I add a counter button?  With the code below, when you click the button nothing changes and the textbox just shows The count is 2'.  I think this is because the page is reloading each time and therefore the Counter object gets 're' instantiated.  So how do I avoid that?

Default.aspx
...

```
<asp:Button ID="bttnCounter" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="ButtonClick"/>
```

...

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{

    Counter counter = new Counter();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bttnCounter.Click += new EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
    }

    public void ButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter.CountUp();
        output.Text = "The count is " + counter.CurrentCount;
    }
}
```

Counter.cs

```
public class Counter
{
    public int CurrentCount { get; private set; }

    public Counter()
    {
        CurrentCount = 0;
    }


    public void CountUp()
    {
        CurrentCount++;
    }
}
```

I may have just completely mis understood this, but when I was using WinForms, I would include the object within the form code.

Answer (score 1):

You should save it in the pages [`ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), since that is the only persistent user-based storage that isn't session bound (you can open the same page multiple times).

```
this.ViewState["someVar"] = yourObject;
```

Retrieve it later:

```
YourClass yourObject = (YourClass)this.ViewState["someVar"];
```

Comment: Also make sure in the page declarations that ViewState is enabled.    Lastly, if you *can* avoid ViewState, please do - that thing can make 12k HTML pages in to monster sizes.     Much easier to do this client-side with a bit of javascript increasing the counter value, than having multiple server roundtrips.   All around a better practice pattern to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the page is loading each time and thus resets your counter to zero each time you click the button.

there are a number of approaches to solve this, the simplest is perhaps to use the Session["counter"] object to store the counter and reload it on page load.

However, as you are new I would suggest you abandon this style of asp.net and instead learn the new MVC version

this has a different approach which avoids many of the page lifecycle problems of asp.net (webforms) although you will still need to store the counter either on the server, or in the page response to the user so it can be sent back in the query string, cookie or whatever